# Nativescript, Can't extend NotificationListenerService using typescript-angular2?

Tags: java, android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm trying to listen to all the notifications that the mobile receive, I'm working with nativescript & angular2,

**First solution I've tried** : -

after installing the tns-platform-declarations package and referencing it

```
 android.service['notification']['NotificationListenerService'].extend({
        onNotificationPosted: (sbn) => {
            console.log("got it");
            console.log(sbn.getNotification().tickerText);
        },
        onCreate: () => {
            console.log("Created");
        }
    });
```

put unfortunately nothing happens on notification posted.

**second try:-**

I've made a java file and place it in

> platforms/android/src/main/java/com/tns/MoNotificationListener.java

```
package com.tns;

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Notification;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.PendingIntent;


public class MoNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

static PendingIntent pickCallIntent ;
static PendingIntent rejectCallIntent ;
static PendingIntent hangCallIntent ;

  @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         Log.d("ReactNative", "Created");
         super.onCreate();

 }


 @Override
 public void onListenerConnected() {
     Log.d("ReactNative", "Got onListenerConnected");


 }

  @Override
  public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
      Log.d("Native", "Got Notification");

      if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {  
        Log.d("Native",sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString());
        Log.d("Native",sbn.getPackageName());
    } 
  }


}
```

tested with

> adb logcat *:S Native:V

and got the logs on notifications posted successfully

add to the android manifest in

> app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
      android:name="com.tns.WheemoNotificationListener"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"

      >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

then I was trying to extend that class from the typescript to get notified on notification posted.

```
android.service['notification']['NotificationListenerService'].extend("com.tns.notification.MoNotificationListener", {
        onNotificationPosted: (sbn) => {
            console.log("got it");
            console.log(sbn.getNotification().tickerText);
        },
        onCreate: () => {
            console.log("Created");
        }
    });
```

**but again nothing happens**

Answer (score 1):

After searching we found that **NotificationListenerService** wasn't available through the default definition file

> android.d.ts

so we used this
[NativeScript/android-dts-generator](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-dts-generator)

 to generate a new one with the latest platform level we needed, and it worked.

thanks all

Comment: hi is there any possibility that you post full code. I need similar solution for `NotificationListenerService`